# codeigniter delete row by id from db

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to delete via codeigniter a page from tbl_pages but i cant success, here is a look on my code:

my router:

```
$route['panelme/pages'] = 'panelcontroller/pageview';
$route['panelme/pages/delete/(:num)'] = 'panelcontroller/pagedelete/$1';
```

and here is my panelcontroller.php:

```
public function pagedelete($pagedeleteid)
    {
        $this->panelme_model->delete_pages($pagedeleteid);
        redirect('panelme/viewpage','refresh');
    }
```

and here is my model:

```
public function delete_pages($pageid)
    {

        $this -> db -> where('id', $pageid);
        $this -> db -> delete('tbl_pages');

    }
```

is there any problem in my code ? because when i call this link:
http://xxxxxxxx.com/panelme/pages/delete/1
i get so many problems that connected to the pages part....any help ?

Comment: the url was `http://xxxxxxxx.com/panelme/page/delete/1` (OR )`http://xxxxxxxx.com/panelme/pages/delete/1`

Comment: @VaraPrasad sorry...was pages not page

Comment: **get so many problems** what are the errors?

Comment: @devpro i get problems like: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: title

Filename: controllers/pages.php

Line Number: 24

Comment: I didn't see title in your controller it must be in other function same file

Comment: i didnt understand...you mean that i must give a title ?

Comment: I said where rcu getting this undefined index notice?

Answer (score 0):

You are using pages in routes:

```
$route['panelme/pages/delete/(:num)'] = 'panelcontroller/pagedelete/$1';
```

So your URL must contains pages not page.

Comment: yeah  i am using pages not page..i just forgot here in stackoverflow to add the s

Comment: Means this is not an answer right what error r u getting on your database error from database.php file @mikha-matta

Comment: Echo $pagedeleteid; in controller chk r u getting values @mikha-matta